# Scrollable EditText inside ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-scrollview

I searched all posts regarding to this subject but still I could not find any solution.
I have one big layout and it is scrollable with ScrollView and it has also EditText with scrollable .
If I try to scroll edittext , layout is starting to scrolling. How I can solve it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/lroot"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"

         >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:onClick="runInfo"
                android:src="@drawable/info_btn" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/splash" />

            <!-- Scrollable EditText -->
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/EditText01"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:autoLink="all"
                android:background="@drawable/isim_soyisim"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:cursorVisible="true"
                android:gravity="left|top"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:longClickable="false"
                android:maxLines="5"
                android:singleLine="false"

            />


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: as per your xml, your layout is supposed to be scrolled....

Comment: encapsulate your EditText with in ScrollView...

Comment: thank you but it did not work

Comment: i tried ur code.for me its working correctly.instead of your iamges i tried with my sample images.can u send with ur iamges.i will try it.

Comment: images are not important, You can use any images which fill your screen then your scrollview work and prevent scrolling of edittext

Comment: we changed layout, if someone solve this problem and share idea, will be appreceated

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.sam.views;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

public class CustomScrollview extends ScrollView{

    public CustomScrollview(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

     public CustomScrollview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        public CustomScrollview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        final int action = ev.getAction();
        switch (action)
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    super.onTouchEvent(ev);
                    break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    return false; // redirect MotionEvents to ourself

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    super.onTouchEvent(ev);
                    break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    return false;

            default: Log.i("VerticalScrollview", "onInterceptTouchEvent: " + action ); break;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        super.onTouchEvent(ev);
         return true;
    }
}
```